# Creating for loop function with accumulative pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, accumulator

I am new to learning JavaScript and need help creating a function that executes a for loop with an accumulative pattern that passes through an array.

What I have written so far will run without error, but it fails to execute the function throughout the entire array "goals"

```
function totalGoals (goals, total) {
    for (i=0, g=goals.length; i<g; i++)
        return (total + goals[i])
}

totalGoals([ 1, 2, 3], 1)
```

What am I doing wrong? I want the function to accumulate every value in the "goals" action.

Comment: Don't use `return` inside the  for loop, use a variable to store the values and return that

Comment: brackets of for loop are not closed,

Comment: What is the expected output of your code?

Comment: Will `totalGoals` always have an array, and then a separate integer, as arguments?

Comment: There is a builtin method for doing that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 2):

The builtin Array [**.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
function totalGoals (goals, total) {
  for (let i = 0; i < goals.length; i++) {
    total += goals[i]
  }
  return total
}
const total = totalGoals([1, 2, 3], 1)
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Could you show me what I would need to change if i wanted this to display each addition separately?

Answer (score 0):

The following code sums the numbers in an array. A for loop enumerates the items in the array, and each time around the loop, an accumulator variable is updated.

```js
function sum(arr) {
 let acc = 0
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   acc += arr[i]
 }
 return acc
}
const result = sum([1, 2, 3])
console.log(result)
```